# Google sheets - How to compare a formula within a cell with a string to spot changes in the formula?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, compare, formula

I help a small business with an application which is entirely run from google sheets and google forms. The issue is that from time to time the business owner will go into the sheet and delete rows of old data. I've noticed that as a result, some of the formulas will change the row which they are looking at. This is despite me using explicit cell references such as $A$1 for example.

So what I would like to do, is use somehow compare the cell which contains the formula, with a string of what the formula should be, then return a value if the formula matches. I had thought an =If function would solve this but so far I am not having any luck.

This is what I have used so far:

Lets say cell **A1** contains the formula I want to check and the formula is (this works fine): ***=FILTER(Dashboard!A2:A, Dashboard!C2:C*1 = TODAY())***

I am using **=IF(A1="=FILTER(Dashboard!A2:A, Dashboard!C2:C*1 = TODAY())",True,False)**

I am expecting the function to compare the value of A1 with my string and return the value **True**. If the formula does not match the string it should return the value **False**.

I currently am returning the value of **False** despite the formula and string being an exact match. I assume this is because my =If statement is looking at the value returned by the =Filter function rather than the formula itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Try: `=IF(FORMULATEXT(A1)="=FILTER(Dashboard!A2:A, Dashboard!C2:C*1 = TODAY())",True,False)`

Comment: @Rory what if the string formula that I want to use as my comparison has quotes within the string "". Lets say the filter formula included a string already within it. It seems to cause an issue within the IF statement.

Comment: Double up any quotes in the formula string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [INDIRECT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) in the place of explicit cell (**$A$1**) reference you mentioned and that should solve the problem of formulas going haywire due to rows deletion in ***Form Responses*** tab. Please do test it out.

```
INDIRECT("Sheet!"&A1)

INDIRECT("A1")
```

Comment: How is this actually related to the question?

Comment: within the Google Form responses tab, when rows of data are deleted, the formulas referencing those ranges dynamically move and that is the reason OP is trying a workaround to keep a check on this using the formula stated above. If INDIRECT() is used in the first place to static-reference the range, this whole workaround setup is not needed at all. @Rory

Comment: Ah - thanks. You're solving the problem at source. :)

Comment: This also does solve my problem now you explained it. I'll impliment this later as it'll take a lot more work given how big this sheet/form set up is. thanks though!